# k8s Prometheus pushgateway basic auth error

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, prometheus-pushgateway

I'm using prometheus-pushgateway helm chart with the latest version **2.6.0**

I've configured basic auth with this [guide](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/auth/basic/), but for some reason it says that my credentials are incorrect

Below is ingress controller logs

> 2024/01/31 16:12:46 [error] 1146#1146: *7443568 user "myuser": password mismatch, client: 10.109.98.17, server: pushgateway.mydomain.com, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", host: "pushgateway.mydomain.com"

despite this when I'm checking generated secret - values are correct

command used to check secret

```
kubectl -n prometheus get secrets prometheus-pushgateway-basic-auth --output="jsonpath={.data.\auth}" | base64 --decode
```

Also the same values are in the /**etc/ingress-controller/auth/passwd** file

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following links below that might help you with your issue:

- [Prometheus-Pushgateway in Azure Managed Prometheus and Grafana](https://blog.devops.dev/streamlining-metrics-collection-with-prometheus-pushgateway-in-azure-managed-prometheus-and-grafana-83c80447c9d4) - Remove host information and only use the service name
- [Securing a Prometheus Pushgateway deployment on OpenShift](https://michaelkotelnikov.medium.com/securing-a-prometheus-pushgateway-deployment-on-openshift-e24125a57ae) - Use route configuration